# Why my two arrays with string elements are not equal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, equality

I have an array which is called ids_to_remove. When I type it in browser inspect, I get the following result:

```
ids_to_remove
(2) ['1', '2']
```

When I type in the same array I get:

```
['1','2']
(2) ['1', '2']
```

When I compare the elements I get:

```
ids_to_remove[0]==='1'
true
ids_to_remove[1]==='2'
true
```

also

```
typeof(ids_to_remove[0])
'string'
```

But when I compare the arrays:

```
ids_to_remove===['1','2']
false
```

Does anyone have any idea why these two arrays are not equal?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Arrays are objects and a comparison of objects is by reference, not by value like you did above

Answer (score 1):

Javascript arrays are objects and you can't simply use the equality operator == to understand if the content of those objects is the same. The equality operator will only test if two objects are actually exactly the same instance (e.g. myObjVariable==myObjVariable, works for null and undefined too).

you can simply use this function:

```
function arrayEquals(a, b) {
    return Array.isArray(a) &&
        Array.isArray(b) &&
        a.length === b.length &&
        a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]);
}
```

This function only works for simple non primitive type arrays.

Comment: Thank you! Actually the reason I compared arrays was I was using ids_to_remove as input for another function and it was not working. When I was simply writing ['1','2'] -manually- in input, it would work so I was trying to understand what is different.